# How to disable the delete button while editing a row in a datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a datagrid where ten rows will be populated with edit and delete buttons.  When I want to edit a row, the edit button will be changed to save and cancel, but if the user clicks on the delete button, it gives me the error, "object references not set to an instance". Please let me know how to handle this?

Comment: at what line this giving exception. show some code.

Comment: when it is accessing the Label data, as the edit will have textboxes and dropdown when clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you just set the "delete button" as disabled while the users edits the entry?
Then when the user clicks save you enabled it again.
Like :

```
private void btnEdit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        yourmethod();
        btnDelete.Enabled = false;
    }
```

and then

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        yourothermethod();
        btnDelete.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Where to make that?can u help?

Comment: As the delete is buttoncolumn and it is in a grid?how to get the id of the delete button?

Comment: Didnt you have to find out the button ID when you change the edit button "to save and cancel" too?
Btw. didnt you chose the button ID by yourself?